# Atom typescript plugin cannot find name 'describe'

Tags: javascript, typescript, atom-editor

I already tried to include a line of typings but that doesnt resolve this issue for me

[image]

here is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "jasmine"
    ]
  }
}
```

the path to node_modules is correct

Comment: What version of typescrpt atom plugin are you using? What is the name of the plugin?

Comment: Would be better to open an issue on github if you think this is a bug. Also add all the details you can for someone to reproduce.

Comment: @prosti latest version of atom and plugin name is atom-typescript

Comment: 10.1.10 is the version then. Can you confirm?

Comment: This is one great plugin and lot of money invested in defeating Microsoft suite.

Comment: Can you confirm you are working on .ts extension file?

Comment: @prosti yes i'm working on a .spec.ts files

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this temporary solution - while I hope that the atom-typescript plugin can solve it better.

Install the types;

```
npm install @types/jasmine --save-dev
```

Added this line into my src/app/app.component.spec.ts file;

```
import  '../../node_modules/@types/jasmine';
```

Didn't need to add it into any other spec files, editing just this one file solves the issue for me.

Another work-around I found, works, but not as good as above for me, so depending on your needs was to edit "package.json", by moving the jasmine reference in the "devDependencies" up to the "dependencies" section;

```
"@types/jasmine": "^2.5.38"
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. To fix it, I removed the **typeRoots**, and just kept the **types** array.

Comment: Hmm. Any ideas *why* this works?  I'm using `typeRoots` to include an extra library of additional type definitions for modules that don't have a common `@type/whatever` type definition module available.  Maybe there's another easy way of doing that without mixing the definitions with my own code?

Answer (score -1):

I've already solved same problem. I'm Atom user too. Just exclude spec.ts files in tsconfig.json. My tsconfig.json looks now like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
        "./src/*.spec.ts",        
    ]
}
```

Read more about tsconfig here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: that's not a solution, you're just avoiding the problem